# How to get a data set from OECD using OECD package in R?

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and am now trying to get data from the OECD website using the "OECD" package. However, I cannot make it work.

The data I would want can be found here https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=REGION_ECONOM#. I want to extract *GVA*, *GVA deflator*, *population* and *GVA* by sector from these tables on the regional level. But every time I use below code, R just doesn't produce any output:

```
library(OECD)

df <- get_dataset("REGION_ECONOM")
```

If any of you could help me I'd be beyond grateful :D

Comment: Please explain *my R just doesn't produce any output*. Empty data frame? A NULL result? Error or warning? As [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/OECD/versions/0.2.3.999/topics/get_datasets) indicate, run `available_datasets_df <- get_datasets()` for a data frame of all available datasets. Does *REGION_ECONOM* appear?

Comment: R simply does not stop working on the command, if that makes any sense? I run the command df<- get_dataset("REGION_ECONOM") and it does not produce the dataframe, all I can do is stop the command from being excecuted

Comment: That should be mentioned in post. Also, did you try the command mentioned?

Comment: I have tried available_datasets_df <- get_datasets() and REGION_ECONOM was in there, so i thought get_dataset("REGION_ECON") would work but maybe it's too big

Comment: Since you download the data unfiltered, it may be pretty big. How long did you let R run? I just tried with a subset (`start_time = 2008`, `end_time = 2009`) and got `HTTP 400 Bad Request` so there may be an issue with the OECD package.

Comment: Approximately 5-7min I think. Just now I tried df <- get_dataset("REGION_ECONOM", c("GVA_TOTAL","GVA_IND_10_VA")) But I got the following error message: 
Error in rsdmx::readSDMX(url) : 
  HTTP request failed with status: 500 Internal Server Error, so maybe i should use an alternative approach. What would be suitable? I could use stata too, if that'd be easier

Comment: `OECD::get_data_structure("REGION_ECONOM")` also took a while to run but did return a result. It was quite slow considering the small amount of data transmitted! The API may simply be broken. The package author warns `The OECD API is currently a beta version and “and in preparation for the full release, the structure and content of datasets are being reviewed and are likely to evolve”. As a result, the OECD package may break from time to time, as I update it to incorporate changes to the API."`. You could raise an issue on [github](https://github.com/expersso/oecd).

Comment: Consider also downloading data from posted link and importing/cleaning in R.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I'll just use the csv data that one can download on the OECD website and pick the variables I need out by hand. Have a great evening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your question, two main issues rise. First, since you did not specif icy any country or region, acquiring the data takes a long time. Second, the `OECD` package is somehow case sensitive, regarding the sequence of filters.

Here is an example to obtain the data you requested, considering only one country (AUD) to simplify the answer.

```
library(OECD)

dataset_list <- get_datasets()
search_dataset("regional", data = dataset_list)
# A tibble: 14 x 2
   id                  title                                                          
   <chr>               <chr>                                                          
 1 REGION_DEMOGR       Regional Demography                                            
 2 REGION_ECONOM       Regional Economy                                               
 3 RWB                 Regional Well-Being                                            
 4 REGION_LABOUR       Regional Labour                                                
 5 REGION_SOCIAL       Regional Social and Environmental indicators                   
 6 REGION_INNOVATION   Regional Innovation                                            
 7 REG_BUSI_DEMOG_COPY Regional Business Demography copy                              
 8 SKILLS_2018_REGION  Skill needs - Regional                                         
 9 REG_BUSI_DEMOG      Regional Business Demography                                   
10 REGION_EDUCAT       Regional Education                                             
11 RFD                 Regional Government Finance and Investment Database            
12 RHPI                National and Regional House Price Indices                      
13 REGION_TYPOL        Regional typology                                              
14 RHPI_TARGET         National and Regional House Price Indices - Headline indicators

dataset <- "REGION_ECONOM"

dstruc <- get_data_structure(dataset)
str(dstruc)
List of 13
 $ VAR_DESC       :'data.frame':    13 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id         : chr [1:13] "TL" "REG_ID" "SERIES" "VAR" ...
  ..$ description: chr [1:13] "Territory Level and Typology" "Region" "SNA Classification" "Indicator" ...
 $ TL             :'data.frame':    17 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:17] "1" "RURB" "1_PU" "1_IN" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:17] "Country" "Country values by rural/urban typology" "     Country - predominantly urban regions" "     Country - intermediate regions" ...
 $ REG_ID         :'data.frame':    3364 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:3364] "AUS" "AU1" "AU101" "AU103" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:3364] "Australia" "New South Wales" "Capital Region" "Central West" ...
 $ SERIES         :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:3] "SNA_2008" "SNA_1993" "SNA_REF"
  ..$ label: chr [1:3] "Last SNA classification (SNA 2008 or latest available)" "Previous SNA classification (SNA 1993, discontinued series)" "Reference data"
 $ VAR            :'data.frame':    49 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:49] "GDP" "GVA_TOTAL" "GVA_IND_TOTAL" "GVA_IND_10_VA" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:49] "Regional GDP" "Regional Gross Value Added, total activities" "Regional Gross Value Added, total activities" "GVA in agriculture, forestry and fishing (ISIC rev4)" ...
 $ MEAS           :'data.frame':    29 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:29] "REG" "CURR_PR" "USD_PPP" "REAL_PR" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:29] "Regional values (in millions)" "      Millions National currency, current prices" "      Millions USD, current prices, current PPP" "      Millions National currency, constant prices, base year 2015" ...
 $ POS            :'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:4] "ALL" "MAX" "MIN" "AVG"
  ..$ label: chr [1:4] "All regions" "Highest regional value in the country by Territorial Level and selected indicators" "Lowest regional value in the country by Territorial Level and selected indicators" "National average"
 $ TIME           :'data.frame':    25 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:25] "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:25] "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" ...
 $ OBS_STATUS     :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:16] "B" "C" "D" "E" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:16] "Break" "Non-publishable and confidential value" "Difference in methodology" "Estimated value" ...
 $ UNIT           :'data.frame':    318 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:318] "1" "GRWH" "AVGRW" "IDX" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:318] "RATIOS" "Growth rate" "Average growth rate" "Index" ...
 $ POWERCODE      :'data.frame':    32 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:32] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:32] "Units" "Tens" "Hundreds" "Thousands" ...
 $ REFERENCEPERIOD:'data.frame':    98 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:98] "2013_100" "2012_100" "2011_100" "2010_100" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:98] "2013=100" "2012=100" "2011=100" "2010=100" ...
 $ TIME_FORMAT    :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id   : chr [1:5] "P1Y" "P1M" "P3M" "P6M" ...
  ..$ label: chr [1:5] "Annual" "Monthly" "Quarterly" "Half-yearly" ...

filter_list1 <- list("", "AUS", "", "GVA_IND_TOTAL")
df1 <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list1)
head(df1)
# A tibble: 6 x 11
  TL    REG_ID SERIES   VAR           MEAS        POS   TIME  POWERCODE UNIT  REFERENCEPERIOD obsValue
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr>              <dbl>
1 1     AUS    SNA_2008 GVA_IND_TOTAL PW_REAL_PPP AVG   1995  0         NA    NA                 67090
2 1     AUS    SNA_2008 GVA_IND_TOTAL PW_REAL_PPP AVG   1996  0         NA    NA                 68908
3 1     AUS    SNA_2008 GVA_IND_TOTAL PW_REAL_PPP AVG   1997  0         NA    NA                 71418
4 1     AUS    SNA_2008 GVA_IND_TOTAL PW_REAL_PPP AVG   1998  0         NA    NA                 73830
5 1     AUS    SNA_2008 GVA_IND_TOTAL PW_REAL_PPP AVG   1999  0         NA    NA                 75869
6 1     AUS    SNA_2008 GVA_IND_TOTAL PW_REAL_PPP AVG   2000  0         NA    NA                 75468

filter_list2 <- list("", "AUS", "", "GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL")
df2 <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list2)
head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  TL    REG_ID SERIES  VAR                MEAS  POS   TIME  POWERCODE obsValue
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
1 1     AUS    SNA_REF GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL RATES ALL   1995  0             60.0
2 1     AUS    SNA_REF GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL RATES ALL   1996  0             60.6
3 1     AUS    SNA_REF GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL RATES ALL   1997  0             61.7
4 1     AUS    SNA_REF GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL RATES ALL   1998  0             61.9
5 1     AUS    SNA_REF GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL RATES ALL   1999  0             63.4
6 1     AUS    SNA_REF GVA_DEFLATOR_TOTAL RATES ALL   2000  0             65.6

filter_list3 <- list("", "AUS", "", "POP_AVG")
df3 <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = filter_list3)
head(df3)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  TL    REG_ID SERIES  VAR     MEAS  POS   TIME  POWERCODE obsValue
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
1 1     AUS    SNA_REF POP_AVG PER   ALL   1995  0         18002000
2 1     AUS    SNA_REF POP_AVG PER   ALL   1996  0         18221700
3 1     AUS    SNA_REF POP_AVG PER   ALL   1997  0         18420200
4 1     AUS    SNA_REF POP_AVG PER   ALL   1998  0         18604800
5 1     AUS    SNA_REF POP_AVG PER   ALL   1999  0         18809600
6 1     AUS    SNA_REF POP_AVG PER   ALL   2000  0         19026200
```

As it can be seen in the `filter_list` elements, we need to add `""` in order to obtain the data for the variable we are interested in. As shown by `dstruc`, the variable (`VAR`) is the fourth element in the sequence. The first one is `TL`, which is left blank. Second, there is the region identification (`REG_ID`). In this example, we set it to `AUS` (Australia). Third, there is the element `SERIES`, which is also left blank.

The package's vignette is really helpful: https://github.com/expersso/OECD.

PS: Sorry for the late reply. Nonetheless, hope this answer helps.